# Run and save pdf from html link

Tags: html

I am opening an invoice portal by giving a reference in the web address bar. Once the invoice portal opens, it has an html link associated to a button, clicking of which opens a pdf in the browser. I then download the pdf to save in local drive using a reference number from the portal.

https://invoice_portal/statements/invoice_number

This is the inspect element of the button which is being clicked
"

```
<button class="_1iKuo" type="button" data-react-toolbox="button"><!-- react-text: 1352 -->See PDF<!-- /react-text --></button>
```

"

This is the element used to name (INV-225) the pdf after downloading.
"

```
<h5 class="_35Wsy">Invoice # INV-225</h5>
```

"

I have hundreds of invoice numbers which i have to open and download the pdf. Is it possible to input the references so that it will automatically opens the portal, click the button and save the pdf in a folder.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap a tag inside button text:

```
<a href="path/to/file" download>Click here to download</a>
```